# SQL list all rows where column A appears more than once but have distinct Column B values

Tags: sql, ms-access, combinations, distinct-values

I have two columns for example, I want to list all the rows where the items in ROW A appears more than once in Column A, but have distinct values in Column B.  So far I have not figured out an answer

```
Column A     Column B
Apple         x
Banana        a
Orange        b
Orange        b
Banana        x
Avocado       d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ColumnA
FROM table t
GROUP BY ColumnA
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnB) >= 2;
```

An alternative `HAVING` clause that might be more efficient is:

```
HAVING MIN(ColumnB) <> MAX(ColumnB)
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine. Here's my SQL Fiddle that I was working on and plugged this query into: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/aa6a5/5/0)

Comment: I am using ms access and i get an undefined function distinct in expression error

Comment: i guess in Access it has to be a nested query, the count and distinct cant be in the same select statement.  do you have any idea.  ive tried some, but cant filter the values to only show those with distinct values in column b

Comment: @JimS . . . You should tag your question with the database you are using.  MS Access is the only such software that doesn't support the very standard `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ColumnA
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY ColumnA
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 AND COUNT(DISTINCT ColumnB) = COUNT(*)
```

- First predicate in `HAVING` clause is true if `ColumnA` value appears more than once.
- Second predicate is true if *all* values in `ColumnB` are distinct within a `ColumnA` group.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3bafd/1)